# $post isnt working with jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, kohana

i have a problem with js $post not working with Jquery mobile.
Basically I have a list of products in my basket, while removing single products works fine with different button, using checkboxes and trying to remove it massively wont work.

Here is the javascript

```
$('.usunZbiorczo').click(function() {

                var zaznaczone = "";

                $(".zaznacz").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                    {

                        zaznaczone = zaznaczone +
                            $(this).val() + "|";
                    }
                });


                if (zaznaczone != "")
                { 

                    $post('<?php echo url::site("koszyk/ajaxUsunZbiorczo/", "http"); ?>', {zaznaczone: zaznaczone}, function(xml) {
                       window.location.replace("/koszyk")
                    });
                }


        //if ($(".zaznacz").filter(':checked').length == 0) return;

        //$('#usunZbiorczo').dialog("open");
        //e.preventDefault();


    });
```

Here is the checkbox:

```
<?php echo form::checkbox("zaznacz_" . $pozycja->ks_Id, $pozycja->ks_Id, false, array("class" => "zaznacz", "data-inline" => "true", "data-iconpos" => "top", "data-mini" => "true", "style"=>"visibility: hidden")) ?>
```

It's from Kohana framework, basically a PHP function that generates simple HTML checkbox code. In array u got standard HTML attributes.

And here is PHP file that recieves it:

```
$zaznaczone = explode("|", $_POST["zaznaczone"]);

    foreach ($zaznaczone as $zazn) {
        if ($zazn == "")
            continue;

        $koszyk = ORM::factory("Koszyk")
                ->where("ks_Id", "=", $zazn)
                ->and_where("ks_uzytkownikId", "=", zalogowany::id())
                ->and_where("ks_magazynId", "=", magazyn::aktualny())
                ->and_where("ks_kontrahentId", "=", kontrahent::aktualny())
                ->find();

        $koszyk->delete();
    }
```

ORM stuff is also from Kohana, basically does stuff in MySQL base. But my problem is that $post in javascript won't even go off... the page does not POST anything to that second PHP.

Oh, here is also the button that starts the whole operation, sorry its also from Kohana, it generates simple  though

```
        <?= html::anchor("#", html::image("media/strona/img/delete.gif") . " " . __('Usuń'), array("class" => "usunZbiorczo", "style" => "margin-left: 10px;")) ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) not $post.